# faulty path to css file in octopress generation

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, octopress

I'm just getting started with Octopress; pretty green on web development, and I'm having the following issue:

When I run `rake generate` to make my octopress page, it mostly generates everything fine but it's not giving a good reference to the .css file. Here is the link it generates:

```
    <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This leaves my index.html page with bare html formatting. But if I change the link to read:

```
    <link href="stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

it works. All I did was take out the forward slash.

My question is this: what do I need to change for `rake generate` to put the proper reference in the html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your Rakefile.

I wrote an article about Rake commands in Octopress here:

http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2013/03/12/rake-commands-in-octopress-on-github/

Inside your main Octopress directory there should be a file called "Rakefile"

Open this file and look for this line:

`desc "Generate jekyll site`

`task :generate do`

In here there is a line that says:

`system "compass compile -css-dir #{source_dir}/stylesheets"`

The `source_dir` is assigned toward the top of the Rakefile where it says `## Misc Configs ##`.

It should say:

`source_dir = "source"`

I gave you almost all the solution. Put these together and try it out to see if you can make it work :)

Comment: Thanks, that mostly got me there. Turns out my issue was in the `document_root` in the Rakefile--or at least changing that to `""` did the trick. Now I'm wondering if this was particular to Nearlyfreespeech, which I'm using for hosting.

Answer (score 1):

A slash in front will point to the root directory of the project.
Whereas without slash, it will point to the current directory of the HTML file

So if in your case, project structure is:

```
Project/something/index.html
```

Any link with `"/stylesheets/"` will point to a folder in the `Project` directory. ie it will look for `"Project/stylesheets"`

Whereas a link with `"stylesheets/"` will point to a folder in the `something` directory, which is the current directory of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new, I'll give you some ideas as to how this can work

--

**Assets**

Firstly, when you make use of the [*asset piepline*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark) in Rails, it does a lot of the work for you. Specifically, the [`stylesheet`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag) feature is very well documented:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "screen" %>
```

If your page has hard-coded references to your stylesheets, it's going to cause all sorts of compatibility issues down the line (with production etc).

I know this is not an answer to your question directly, but you need to ensure your HTML files are making use of the `Rails` helper methods - these create dynamic paths, which your app will automatically follow

--

**Generate**

As for your generator, I've got no experience with octopress

If the gem is not written by you, I would not worry about the `generator` too much. Having written my own gems & other software, it's very difficult to create a system which works for every single system

If you have the ability to change the path yourself (after generation), I'd do that, and raise an issue with the author on Github